# Scala - passing defined values for optional parameters within routes file

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, custom-routes

So I have a routes file that calls a controller with several optional inputs. as per below

```
GET      /1.0/*path/documents             
controllers.DocumentController.list(path, format: Option[String], ref: Option[String], build: Option[String], files: Option[String], token: Option[String])
```

I'm looking to customize a URI that would pass defined or provided values for these options, specifically I'm looking to pass :ref & :build from the URI into their respective options below without changing the underlying controller or model calls.

```
GET      /1.0/*path/documents/:ref.:build         
controllers.DocumentController.list(path, format: Option[String], Some(ref), Some(build), files: Option[String], token: Option[String])
```

Currently the above gives this error.

> ')' expected but '(' found.

I've been using scala for ~3 weeks and have little formal training in OO or MVC development so  please go easy on me :)

SOLUTION: Method must be defined to take these parameters as part of a function method rather than as options. see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional arguments can only be provided with the query option after the URL.  Take for example the below route:

```
GET      /1.0/*path/documents        
controllers.DocumentController.list(path, format: Option[String], Option[ref], Option[build], files: Option[String], token: Option[String])
```

These parameters can be provided by using a query appended to the URI after `?`.

For example:

```
http://localhost:9000/1.0/pathvariable/documents?format=json&ref=master
```

If the desired customized route is:

```
GET      /1.0/*path/documents/:ref.:build
```

Then the `ref` and `build` variables should not be defined as options but as regular input parameters that must be provided.

Below example where list 2 is a new method taking the 3 parameters as well as some optional parameters:

```
GET      /1.0/*path/documents/:ref.:build
controllers.DocumentController.list2(path, ref: String, build: String, format: Option[String], files: Option[String], token: Option[String])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the same compilation error than you when testing, but
1. I think that the dot after the `:ref` is not authorized and should be a slash.
2. If you want to use an option, specify it like this:

```
GET      /path      controllers.DocumentController.list(format: Option[String])
```

And call it like this:

```
/path?format=myString
```

Comment: Apologies so the :ref.:build above is part of a versioning system ie. URL would be **/1.0/documents/v3.1.1** where the **v3.1** is the ref parameter and the **1** is the build parameter. Can I specify a route like this (replacing . for another character is fine) or am I restricted to using the query syntax like what you have listed above for optional inputs?

Comment: You can mix them like this: GET /path/:ref controllers.DocumentController.list(ref: String, format: Option[String]) and call it like /path/myRef?format=myString

Comment: ok so I can access the options like this:  **/path/myRef?format=myString&build=myBuild** but not some custom way like this **/path/myRef.myString.myBuild** ?

Comment: No, I'm almost sure that it's not possible

Comment: You can accept my answer if the response satisfies you ;)